# What's wrong with this sort LinkedList of Structs?

Tags: c, sorting, struct, singly-linked-list

I have the following code to create a singly linked list populated with "Job" structs.

I would like to sort them based on the 'time_to_complete' member of the structs, but I can't seem to get the sorting to work. I went over it with some tutors and spent a lot of time trying to find a solution that works for me, but no luck.

I am pretty new to C, so it may not be as beautiful as it can be, but I just need the basic functionality to work on the sorting and I have exhausted my resources.

The code is below running on a Macbook Air with OSX Catalina:

```
//Struct for nodes which will comprise the priority queue
struct Job{
    int type;                   //Keeps track of the type
    int ID;                     //Keeps track of the unique node ID to differentiate between jobs
    float time_to_complete;     //Keeps track of time the job will take
    struct Job* next;           //Pointer to the next shortest Job
};

//Constructor for Job structs for easier initialization
struct Job jobCreator(int type, int ID, float time_to_complete, struct Job* next){
    struct Job job;
    job.ID = ID;
    job.time_to_complete = time_to_complete;
    job.type = type;
    job.next = next;
    return job;
}

//Helper function to print the members of any given job struct
void printJob(struct Job* job){
    if(job->ID){
        printf("Data for job%i\n", job->ID);
    }else{
        printf("Error, job is not initialized\n");
    }
    if(job->type){
        printf("--Type: %i\n", job->type);
    }else{
        printf("Error, job type is not initialized\n");
    }
    if(job->time_to_complete){
        printf("--TTC: %f\n", job->time_to_complete);
    }else{
        printf("Error, job TTC is not initialized\n");
    }
    if(job->next){
        printf("--Points to: job%i\n", ((job)->next)->ID);
    }else{
        printf("Error, job next is not initialized\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
};

//Stub for swap
void Swap(struct Job* parent, struct Job* child){
    struct Job tempNode = jobCreator(parent->type, parent->ID, parent->time_to_complete, parent->next);
    
    //Copy over child members to parent members
    parent->ID = child->ID;
    parent->type = child->type;
    parent->time_to_complete = child->time_to_complete;
    child->next = parent->next;
    parent->next = child->next;
    
    //Copy the tempNode members to child members
    child->ID = tempNode.ID;
    child->type = tempNode.type;
    child->time_to_complete = tempNode.time_to_complete;
    child->next = NULL;
}


//Adds a new job to the end of the priority queue
void addJobPriority(struct Job* currentNode, struct Job* newJob){
    while(currentNode->next){
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    currentNode->next = newJob;
}

//Helper method to sort the queue
void sortQueue(struct Job* rootNode, int jobCounter){
    struct Job* minNode = rootNode; //Temp copy of the root at start
    float minNodeVal = minNode->time_to_complete;
    struct Job* tempNode = rootNode;
    
    printf("Entering the while loop\n");
    for(int i=0;i<jobCounter;i++){
        while(minNode->next){ //While the node has a child
            if((minNode->next)->time_to_complete < minNodeVal){ //If the next node TTC is less than the minNodeVal, move to the next node
    //            minNode = minNode->next;
                minNodeVal = (minNode->next)->time_to_complete;
            }else{ //If the parent TTC is greater than or equal to its child TTC
                //Swap
                break;
            }
            tempNode = minNode;
            minNode = minNode->next;
        }
        Swap(tempNode, minNode);
    }
}

//Driver
int main(){
    //TEST
    //Job declarations
    struct Job job1;
    struct Job job2;
    job1 = jobCreator(1, 1, 1.0, NULL);
    job2 = jobCreator(2, 2, 2.0, NULL);
    int jobCounter = 2;

//TEST FOR SORT
    addJobPriority(&job2, &job1);
    printf("job2, job1:\n");
    printJob(&job1);
    printJob(&job2);
    printf("Sorting...\n");
    sortQueue(&job1, jobCounter);
    printf("Printing states after the swap job1, job2\n");
    printJob(&job1);
    printJob(&job2);
    
    //Return 0 on success
    return 0;
    
}
```

Ideally this should show that job1 links to job2 which links to job3 which links to job4.

Output with two jobs as example:

```
job2, job1:
Data for job1
--Type: 1
--TTC: 1.000000
Error, job next is not initialized

Data for job2
--Type: 2
--TTC: 2.000000
--Points to: job1

Sorting...
Entering the while loop
Printing states after the swap job1, job2
Data for job1
--Type: 1
--TTC: 1.000000
Error, job next is not initialized.  <----This should point to job2

Data for job2
--Type: 2
--TTC: 2.000000
--Points to: job1.                   <----This should point to Null and 
                                          print "error, job next is not 
                                          initialized"
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, try to reproduce the problem with just two jobs. That is not just a requirement for SO debugging help questions but is also a standard technique for anyone doing debugging. Also provide the expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I apologize - still pretty new to stack overflow. I will edit the question to include that information. :)

Comment: Please let me know if that is clear enough or if I should add more/different stuff. Happy to add more if it is helpful, just not sure what else is needed :)

Comment: The code and the output need to match exactly. That is, show the exact code that produces that exact output.

Comment: Gotcha, I changed the code to only display the consequential parts. Now it doesn't have any comments that don't inform about the logic, unused elements are gone, and the print statements have been cleaned up.

Comment: Since you pass a pointer to the root node `struct Job* rootNode` to `sortQueue()`, any changes you make to the pointer will not be seen back in the calling function because `sortQueue()` receives a copy of the original pointer. You need to pass the address of the original pointer struct `Job** rootNode` so you can operate on (or change) the value at the original pointer address.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, David. So I would change `struct Job* rootNode` to `struct Job rootNode` and make the necessary changes to the member access calls?

Comment: Further, where do you initialize the `->next` pointer for list operations at all? You pass `NULL` to `jobCreator()` for the `next` node and the only other time you work with the next member is in `swap()` or in `addJobPriority()` where you make `job2` the current job and set `job1` as the `next`.  I fail to see how this is creating a list.

Comment: addJobPriority builds the linked list as it goes, so every time I want to add a job to the list I call that function which assigns the pointer of the last node to the new job struct. The structure of the list, then, is imposed by the relationship of these one way pointers. Originally I had 4 jobs that constituted the list, but at the suggestion of another comment simplified to two.

Comment: Here is an example of sorting a linked list you may find helpful [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB). You can either add nodes in order or sort them later. (note a mergesort is much quicker)

Comment: Thank you for the link! I will study it and see what I can apply to this case.

Comment: Okay, so you are *forward-chaining* your nodes in `addJobPriority()`. You might want to consider refactoring your code so your list operations take all data and build the list in-order. Then the only rewiring you would need would be if you change a priority. The only reason I suggest this is what you have bears little resemblance to how you would normally build a list. You are free to break it up however, but I would envision you having a priority to provide to `jobCreator()` so you are building the list with that "add" function. It's just hard to follow.

Comment: That's interesting, I hadn't thought of that. So one way I could do it is pass in my list, break it up into nodes, order them, then return the reconstructed list?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in two primary ways. (1) read/construct list, sort by priority later, or (2) if a job will have a priority at the time it is added to the list, just `addinorder()` as shown in the example.If a note's priority changes, just iterate in the list (using both the address of the pointer and pointer) until you find the node that sorts before the node that changed and set that `->next` to the node that changed and the `->next` for the changed node to what was the `->next` for the one that sorted before it. You iterate until you both position and removed the changed node.